# Store files in ftp server, accessible only for users from authentication server via OAuth2 protocol and separately for each other

Tags: ftp, authentication, oauth2

We have in company authentication server with support of OAuth 2 protocol.
We are thinking about ftp repository.

Could it be possible to configure ftp repository/server so that we could provide files only for users from authentication server (these users are not in local /etc/passwd list). And each user should see only files assigned to him ?

Thank you for any notice, how to solve this or if it is possible.

Comment: Why FTP and not HTTP?

Comment: FTP is not mandatory. If problem is solvable with HTTP also could used.

Comment: If your company already uses GSuite or M365 you can deliver this straight out of the box

Comment: According this link should be possible to autenticate through LDAP: https://www.golinuxcloud.com/configure-ftp-server-auth-users-ad-linux/